# Word/adjective to for first and next post/thread

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So, I am making a graph and want to label threads/posts which is categorized as:

1. first threads posted by users
2. second, third and next threads posted by users.

What adjective can I use to describe these? ____ threads.

What I have in mind:

1. first and repeat threads
2. first and subsequent threads
3. rookie and nonrookie threads

Comment: How about "new" threads and "follow-up" threads?

Comment: You could use *maiden* thread for the first thread, but if later threads are unrelated, I would avoid *follow-up* and stick with *subsequent*.

Comment: I'd agree. Subsequent fits nicely

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s enough information to make useful suggestions.
When you say ‘threads/posts’ does mean two separate categories, ‘threads’ and ‘posts’ or does it mean you want the words ‘threads’ and ‘posts’ to be interchangeable and apply to the same thing or what, please?

You have two sets of examples but it’s not clear how or why or even whether they really relate to each other.
Are you asking readers to choose one of the three items in the second list as most suitable for covering all the possibilities in the first list?

Your first list seems to suggest first, second, third and next threads but there is no explanation why it’s not, for instance, first, second, third, fourth, and fifth.
Then first, second, third and next suggests you’re interested only in threads up to four… but in that case why not just say so? ‘Next’ here is just confusing.

Assuming ‘What adjective can I use to describe these? ____ threads’ refers to the first pair, does that mean you want two adjectives, one for the first threads posted by users and the other for second, third and next threads, or one that describes both groups?

Whatever else it’s doing, ‘first and repeat…’ is stretching a point, unless it's in the sems of 'Trolls are people who repeat the same noxious rubbish over and again…'.

If you’re suggesting ‘first and subsequent…’ instead then it’s prolly better but ‘subsequent’ seems to ask for confusion. Do you want it to literally mean ‘subsequent’ or merely ‘later’? Subsequent posts in the same thread or later posts in any thread or either way, threads or posts alone or both separately or both in the same tally?

From one perspective Monzoor’s ‘new’ and ‘follow-up’ seems helpful but in and of itself, it caters only for subsequent posts in the same thread. What any of us says on one topic is certainly not a ‘follow-up’ to anything said in another, even if ’subsequent’ refers only to time and not also to subject.

Is it right to guess that ‘rookie and nonrookie’ should try to distinguish between the first and anything else a user posts?
At a vague guess I’d have to suggest you’re not trying to determine how many posts each User makes, because that would leave ‘first’ or ‘maiden’ or ‘rookie’ as a redundant category, wouldn’t it?
Is it true that ‘first/…’ can only be relevant in measuring what percentage of users make more than one post?